# Post login request with request-promise does'nt work http request

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, httprequest, request-promise

Hello I have a problem with request-promise.

I try to navigate on a website with http request I try this code.

```
const rp = require('request-promise');

const userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_4) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133 Safari/537.36';
const url = "https://example/process_login";

const _include_headers = function(body, response, resolveWithFullResponse) {
    return {
        'headers': response.headers, 
        'data': body, 
        'finalUrl': response.request.uri.href, // contains final URL
    };
};

const options = {
    uri: url,
    followAllRedirects: true,
    method: 'post',
    gzip: true,
    transform: _include_headers,
    headers: {
        'User-Agent': userAgent
    },form :{
      username: 'xxxxxx',
      password: 'xxxxxx'
    },
    followRedirect : true,
    resolveWithFullResponse: false,
    simple : true,
    redirect_uri:'https://example/secured/mon-espace-membre?fromLogin=true'
};

rp.get('https://example/authentification').then(function(response2, body){
      /* console.log("respnse " + response2);
       console.log("Body " + body);*/

       return rp(options).then(function(response, body){

        console.log(response);
        console.log(body);

        return rp.get('https://example/secured/mon-espace-membre').then(function(response1, body){
          /* console.log("respnse " + response1);
           console.log("Body " + body);*/
         }).catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
         });    
    });
     }).catch(function(error) {
      console.log(error);
     });
```

Can I navigate on a website with http request with nodejs?
I want to chain request to access on a specific page.

Comment: what specific problem are you having with this code?

Comment: I want to display the last get **return rp.get('https://example/secured/mon-espace-membre')** but the response data is the login page. Never display the last get. I want to know how to log and display the protected page and continue http request to navigate on the website

Comment: Logins are usually done with cookies.  The server sends you an id of some kind, which will be in the response somewhere like `response.cookies` (not sure exactly).  You then need to send back the cookies with each `rp.get`.  There should be an option to add cookies to the request with `rp.get`.  Note - the website my have additional checks against web scraping, e.g. generating a random value to insert into the markup of forms and then checking that it receives that value on the backend.